# Pass/set `current directory` to/for a shell script from Java in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, java, paths

While trying to automate an installation process in Ubuntu 16.04 with a `.jar` file, I did not know how to solve the following problem:

**Problem description**

Part of the installation files automatically generate the following file called `generate` in location `/usr/share/taskd/pki/`:

```
generate                                                                                                                  
#!/bin/sh

# For a public or production server, purchase a cert from a known CA, and skip
# the next step.

# For development, testing and personal server management, create a CA key and
# cert, and use that to generate a server key and cert.  Creates:
#   ca.key.pem
#   ca.cert.pem
#   server.key.pem
#   server.cert.pem

./generate.ca
./generate.server

# Generate a certificate revocation list (CRL).  The initial CRL is empty, but
# can grow over time.  Creates:
#   server.crl.pem

./generate.crl

# The above is sufficient to operate a server.  What follows is a per-client
# process.  Creates:
#   ${1}.key.pem
#   ${1}.cert.pem

./generate.client client
```

I have a java project that executes the installation commands,which I run from location `/mnt/c/example folder/setup.jar`. The java code that runs the command consists of: `p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[] command)` and the actual command under consideration is created by:

```
commands[10] = new String[2]
commands[10][0] = "sudo";
commands[10][1] = "/usr/share/taskd/pki/generate";
```

Whereas the original shell command is:

```
cd /usr/share/taskd/pki
sudo ./generate
```

To solve my `xy`-problem of running the `./generate` file, I can

1. Create it in java with absolute paths, (copy it to the `/usr/share/taskd/pki/` folder) and run it.
2. Create a shell command that actually executes the commands, instead of a `.jar` file.

**Question**

However, I was wondering how I can pass the "current directory" of `/usr/share/taskd/pki/` to the shell script named `generate` in that location, such that the `./generate.ca`, `./generate/server`, `./generate.crl` and `./generate.client client` are executed correctly/found.

**Attempts**

Initially I tried to `cd` to `root` and from `root` to `/usr/share/taskd/pki/` with the `.jar` file, however I learned that the `cd` command is not effective when used from within the `.jar`.

**Doubts**

This might seem like purely a programming question which should be posted in Stack Overflow, but I think the essence is platform specific; how to pass environments/paths in Ubuntu between 2 scripts in different locations. I currently cannot predict whether the final answer will be generally applicable to Linux or Ubuntu 16.04. If this perspective or assumption is incorrect please let me know.

Comment: @DKBose thank you, that was indeed a typo that I corrected.

Comment: So you essentially want to change the working directory of the process started from java?

Comment: Ah, thank you, assuming it is that process started from java, that also contains/runs the `.generate`, then that is indeed what I am trying to do. I was not aware of the difference between the working directory and the current directory. I will research again using the "working directory" terminology. With an emphasis on the containment within the `.jar` script. So essentially what you said, without running scripts before, after or in between the execution of the `.jar` script (with the exception of the `.generate` script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you should use [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of `Runtime.exec()`.

ProcessBuilder has some nice features like the ability to modify environment variables or **setting the working directory**.

Here an example:

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add("./generate");

File workingDirectory = new File("/usr/share/taskd/pki/");

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.directory(workingDirectory);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I am a bit confused though, since I was about to close this post as a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java thanks to your previous comment yielding a new research therm "working directory". In that post, the main answer states that it is not possible. I will work on implementing your solution, but could you perhaps explain the discrepancy between possibility of your solution, and the claimed impossibility in the referred solution?

Comment: The OP in the question you found asked for changing the working directory of the JVM. The reason was that instantiating a `new File("relative/path")` will result in a file path relative to the working directory of the JVM. If that File was created running `/absolute/path/jar.jar`, the resulting absolute file path would be `/absolute/path/relative/path`. Changing the working directory of the currently running JVM is apparently not possible. You, on the other hand, want to start a new Process in a specific working directory, which is perfectly possible.